# How to hidden name end url index.html

Tags: html, linux, .htaccess

What I mean by last name in the url, like index.html for example the url link on my website homepage. the result is like this

`https://hijaben.insomnia247.nl/index.html`

I want to remove or delete the last name of the url `(index.html)`

I tried using the .htaccess file but it didn't work at all. Is it possible the script is wrong or the VPS doesn't support or what? the solution ..?

**File .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What program are you using to run the server? lampp(xammp for linux)?

Comment: I use linux server

Comment: Usually by default a web server shows the page named index in the root directory. Obiously this doesn't apply if you are using some framework like django or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

Please check this out im sure it can help you with your problem sir.

https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/how-to-set-up-htaccess-on-apache/

Comment: @Gusman Yes sir, let me know if it works for you if not ill find some more solutions. If this helped please upvote and accept my answer with the checkmark found to the left :)

Comment: but unfortunately it's a setting for admin rights, and I only user doesn't have access to such settings. and the server that I use is Debian

Comment: Can you not use su in terminal to log in as sudo

Comment: @Gusman Also Debian is still a Linux distribution - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian

Comment: for the options and solutions that I got earlier by searching for various sources, finally I can use the file name without the end of html, as long as the contents of the file must be ```<html> ``` or ```<(php```

I have applied successfully, from index.html to index for the home page, as well as for other pages, concat, team, high five, blog.

but every time you return to the homepage you want it to be redirected from any page, it still becomes index.html for the home page.

Comment: Give me a minute to search some more

Comment: I can't enter the sudo command, unless the admin gives my username to the sudo command, but unfortunately it can't.

Comment: I haven't been able to, thank you guys for the enlightenment, I want to rest a little first, maybe we can continue again after finishing the break.

Comment: @Gusman Yes sir that isn't no problem just reply to this comment and ill try to further assist you.

Comment: can't get the solution yet

Comment: if the problem is on Linux OS, I think it's wrong because I once installed wordpress and .htaccess it works fine

Comment: @Gusman Yes sir linux is good and all but sometimes stuff just doesn't work. Im not bashing on linux though that is my secondary operating system i use for programming. Im glad it is working now sir and i hope you a great day sir.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate things with unnecessary `mod_rewrite`. Just use `DirectoryIndex index.html`.

Comment: so what is the htaccess script that is wrong, or what should I edit?
sorry it's still a beginner